# How to create a stopwatch in React using useReducer hook and setInterval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to figure out how to implement useReducer in my stopwatch app that I made a while ago that uses setState. I am having lots of trouble implementing it, and I feel like my confusion centers around how the reducer function actually works.

The major problem that I am having is that I am not sure how the reducer function actually works, as I am having trouble implementing the logic for the timer buttons. And I am assuming that I should be putting the logic in the switch statement.

Here is my actual code:

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react"


function init(initialState) {
  return { time: initialState }
}

let initialState = {
  timerOn: true,
  timerStart: 0,
  timerTime: 0
};



function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'start timer':
      return startTimer()
    case 'reset timer':
      return zerotimer(initialState)
    case 'resume timer':
      return
    default:
      return state
  }
}


function zerotimer(initialState) {
  return { initialState };
}

function startTimer(initialState) {
  this.timer = setInterval(() => {
    this.setState({
      timerTime: Date.now() - this.state.timerStart
    });
  }, 10);
}

function Timer({ initialState }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
  let centiseconds = (Math.floor(initialState / 10) % 100);
  let seconds = (Math.floor(initialState / 1000) % 60);
  let minutes = (Math.floor(initialState / 60000) % 60);
  let hours = (Math.floor(initialState / 3600000));
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h2>Time to run!</h2>
        </div>
        <div>Stopwatch</div>
        <div>
          {hours} : {minutes} : {seconds} : {centiseconds}
        </div>
        {state.timerOn === false && state.timerTime === 0 && (
          <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'start timer' })}>Start</button>
        )}
        {state.timerOn === true && (
          <button onClick={this.stopTimer}>Stop</button>
        )}
        {state.timerOn === false && state.timerTime > 0 && (
          <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Resume</button>
        )}
        {state.timerOn === false && state.timerTime > 0 && (
          <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'reset timer' })}>Reset</button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Timer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal implementation using `useState` first, then below I'll cover the `useReducer` case.

I dropped the `hours`, and removed a few other things to make it simpler.

**Using `useState` :**

```
// import React from "react";
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Timer(props) {
  const [centiseconds, setCentiseconds] = useState(0);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0);
  const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);

  useInterval(() => {
    if (!timerOn) return;

    setCentiseconds((centiseconds) =>
      centiseconds === 99 ? 0 : centiseconds + 1
    );
  }, 10);

  useInterval(() => {
    if (!timerOn) return;

    setSeconds((seconds) => (seconds === 59 ? 0 : seconds + 1));
  }, 1000);

  useInterval(() => {
    if (!timerOn) return;

    setMinutes((minutes) => (minutes === 59 ? 0 : minutes + 1));
  }, 60000);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {String(minutes).padStart(2, "0")} : {String(seconds).padStart(2, "0")}{" "}
        : {String(centiseconds).padStart(2, "0")}
      </div>
      {timerOn === false && (
        <button onClick={() => setTimerOn(true)}>Start</button>
      )}
      {timerOn === true && (
        <button onClick={() => setTimerOn(false)}>Stop</button>
      )}
      {
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setTimerOn(false);
            setCentiseconds(0);
            setSeconds(0);
            setMinutes(0);
          }}
        >
          Reset
        </button>
      }
    </>
  );
}

// source: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Timer />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

From here, it's pretty straightforward to convert it into `useReducer`.

What you need to do is replace the `setState` calls with actions, and handle the actions in the reducer.
It's honestly an overkill for this case, and it's too much boilerplate code, but here it is anyway.

**Using `useReducer`:**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const initialState = {
  centiseconds: 0,
  seconds: 0,
  minutes: 0,
  timerOn: false,
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "START":
      return {
        ...state,
        timerOn: true,
      };
    case "STOP":
      return {
        ...state,
        timerOn: false,
      };
    case "RESET":
      return initialState;
    case "SET_CENTISECONDS":
      return {
        ...state,
        centiseconds: action.payload.centiseconds,
      };
    case "SET_SECONDS":
      return {
        ...state,
        seconds: action.payload.seconds,
      };
    case "SET_MINUTES":
      return {
        ...state,
        minutes: action.payload.minutes,
      };

    default:
      return initialState;
  }
};

function Timer(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const { centiseconds, seconds, minutes, timerOn } = state;

  useInterval(() => {
    if (!timerOn) return;

    dispatch({
      type: "SET_CENTISECONDS",
      payload: {
        centiseconds: centiseconds === 99 ? 0 : centiseconds + 1,
      },
    });
  }, 10);

  useInterval(() => {
    if (!timerOn) return;

    dispatch({
      type: "SET_SECONDS",
      payload: {
        seconds: seconds === 59 ? 0 : seconds + 1,
      },
    });
  }, 1000);

  useInterval(() => {
    if (!timerOn) return;

    dispatch({
      type: "SET_MINUTES",
      payload: {
        minutes: minutes === 59 ? 0 : minutes + 1,
      },
    });
  }, 60000);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {String(minutes).padStart(2, "0")} : {String(seconds).padStart(2, "0")}{" "}
        : {String(centiseconds).padStart(2, "0")}
      </div>
      {timerOn === false && (
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "START" })}>Start</button>
      )}
      {timerOn === true && (
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "STOP" })}>Stop</button>
      )}
      {<button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "RESET" })}>Reset</button>}
    </>
  );
}

// source: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Timer />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This is not the only way to accomplish this. You can use `useReducer` however you want. You can pass the new state you want to be merged instead of passing an action, similar to `setState` in react classes. ([check this article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-implement-usestate-with-usereducer)).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I appreciate it.